# Auto Height in LibreOffice Calc

Tags: phpexcel, libreoffice-calc

Typical you would format auto height rows with PHPExcel like this:

```
$file = new PHPExcel();
$file->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.');
$file->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);
$file->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($file, 'Excel2007');
$writer->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
```

The problem is this doesn't work well when you open such a file with LibreOffice Calc. Instead you have to select the cell, choose `Format Cells...` and click `OK`.

It seems this is a [known bug](https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/429322) but unfortunately the proposed solution by adding the following `else` block into [`Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\Worksheet.php` at line 1004](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007/Worksheet.php#L1004) doesn't seem to work:

```
else {
    $objWriter->writeAttribute('customHeight', 'false');
    $objWriter->writeAttribute('ht', '0');
}
```

How could this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like that's a known bug in Libre Office. Detailed discussion here: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/429322

Comment: that link is broken.